# Добавление столбца в DataFrame, заполняемого результатом поиска подстроки в существующем столбце

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть DataFrame, загружаемый из csv-файла (это получается).

Надо сформировать (добавить) столбец, заполняемый цифрами, идущими после *totalSum=* в столбце F15 исходного DataFrame.
В итоге родилась конструкция

```py
df['totS'] = str(re.findall(r'\d{1,}', str(re.findall(r'totalSum=\d{1,}', str(df['F15'])))))
```

Но результат такой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запутался с преобразованием типов данных, как я понимаю. Прошу подсказки.
А может, есть более изящное решение.

Comment: Поправьте вопрос!! Вы про Markdown знаете??

Comment: Вопрос поправил, спасибо за замечание.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вопрос только в извлечении цифр из строки после `totalSum=`, то это легко решается с помощью метода `str.extract()` и регулярного выражения с последующим преобразованием в число:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'F15': ['totalSum=12345#sdlknfancs', 'totalSum=     412156!это сумма!', 'totalSum= 412.156', 'totalSum= 117.25.800']})
df['new'] = df.F15.str.extract(r'totalSum=\s*([\d]+\.?[\d]*)').astype(float)
print(df)
```

```
                               F15         new
0        totalSum=12345#sdlknfancs   12345.000
1  totalSum=     412156!это сумма!  412156.000
2                totalSum= 412.156     412.156
3             totalSum= 117.25.800     117.250
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, проверил у себя - работает.

Answer (score 1):

Если во всех строках столбца разделитель одинаковый и дальше идут только искомые цифры, то можно попробовать

```
df['totS'] = df['F15'].astype(str).str.split('totalSum=', expand=True)[1]
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, безусловно, полезный, но в данном случае дальше идут не только цифры, но и другие символы. Сразу за цифрами - решётка (#). Но решёток в строке много. Главное, если мой скрипт с двумя проходами использовать для поиска просто в одной строке - он работает. Не работает в DataFrame.

Comment: Тогда попробуй обернуть свою функцию в ".apply ( lambda x: " - применяет твою функцию отдельно к каждой строке

Должно выйти что то вроде:
df['totS'] = df['F15'].apply ( lambda x: str(re.findall(r'\d{1,}', str(re.findall(r'totalSum=\d{1,}', str(df['F15']))))) )

Comment: Только у тебя будет возвращать ответ сразу для всех в каждую строчку, нужно будет изменить функцию под конкретную строчку, чтобы обработка была только для нее

Comment: Да, я попробовал с lambda, но всё равно в результирующем столбце в каждой строке - [], как и в моём первом варианте. Пустой список (list), как я понимаю.

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря подсказке коллеги radjaz родилось громоздкое, но работающее решение вопроса:

```
df_gin2s_sel['totS_1'] = df_gin2s_sel['F15'].astype(str).str.split('totalSum=', expand=True)[1].astype(str).str.split('#', expand=True)[0]
```

Это главное. Но всё равно что-то с типами данных не то -

```
SettingWithCopyWarning:
```

A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead